# How to deserialize a CSV file stream?

Tags: java, csv, deserialization

I'm getting back into Java after 8 years away.

I have a file upload HTML page:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

from where I upload a CSV file.

`/upload` maps to a servlet that implements the `doPost` method:

```
  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
  FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);

  while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    FileItemStream item = iterator.next();
    InputStream stream = item.openStream();

    if (!item.isFormField()) {
      int len;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
      while ((len = stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        // do some deserialization here..?
      }
    }

  }
```

I'm really hoping there's a better way than the manually parsing approach. I'm reading about the `Serializable` interface - is this something I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: It's still a little weird for me when people edit my questions. I understand adding/removing tags, and obvious edits (e.g. typos/errors), but why any inconsequential/personal comments in the question? Is this something I should just get used to?

Comment: That edit was a bit destructive...I added the [tag:apache-commons-fileupload] tag because it is very relevant (it's the library you're using). I'm not sure why @ArtB removed it, or your comments, but you're more than free to change it back :)

Comment: @HoundDog I don't see why it matters where the InputStream is coming from and I was trying to focus on the specific problem he was addressing aside from the details surrounding. If you want you can change it back, but my edit did get reviewed and approved so I don't think I was totally off-base.

Comment: Didn't mean to take us off topic too much :) Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you've already looked at the [user guide](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/streaming.html) for commons fileupload based on your code.

You can easily pass the input stream from commons fileupload into a CSV library such as [Super CSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net) instead of writing your own stream reading code. You can even read the CSV as a POJO (i.e. Javabean). Take a look at the [examples](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html).

Your code will only differ from the examples in that you're reading from an InputStream instead of a File, so creating the reader will look something like:

```
ICsvBeanReader beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(
    new InputStreamReader(stream), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
```

If you don't actually want to read the CSV file (you might want to persist it or email it, for example), then you can use Commons IO's [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) to read it into a byte array.

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
```

Oh, and welcome back to Java :)

Answer (score 1):

There is the [CSVReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/) library.

The `Serializable` interface is for storing an object's state to a bytestream. Think of it as saving a game to a save file (with similar reprecussions if you upgrade your version and then try to reload an old save).